# Altera FPGA Pinout help

Tags: fpga, output, input, intel-fpga

I recently bought an Altera FPGA Cyclone II board off of ebay, it says BAIXUN on the LCD display. It didnt come with any documentation. I'm trying to program the FPGA board but I have no idea what pin location my LED's and buttons and such are located at. Is there a built in tool where I can toggle different pins and see what happens to the outputs and vice versa for the inputs? I'm trying to create a cheatsheet for myself of where all my inputs and outputs are located?

Thanks

Comment: Throw it away and get a board with documentation!

Comment: Post the eBay link and make sure it isn't just a clone of another board. There are also youtube videos which mention "baixun", e.g. https://youtu.be/MqRLqW3EUSo where people claim to have documentation and sample code. Next time, research documentation before buying off eBay. That lesson is usually learnt the hard way, so don't feel too bad.

Answer (score 1):

There are various tools that can be used to probe bins via JTAG boundary scan.  You will have to obtain a BSDL file for the chip in question so that the tool knows which bits correspond to which pins.  You will also need a compatible JTAG cable.  I have a tool called ftjrev (https://github.com/alexforencich/ftjrev) which can be used to back out pin assignments on complex boards using an FT2232-based JTAG cable.

It would also be a good idea to contact the seller and see if they have any documentation that they can email you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there not any built in way to see which pin is being toggled in the quartus II software? And I will look in to the BSDL file you mentioned.

Comment: Not really.  You could write some HDL to do that, but the chip already has a boundary scan chain on it, so you might as well just use that.